# How to check radio button with radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having radio button with value YES and NO.Like this

```
<input type="radio" name="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED" data-role="none" value="YES" onclick="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED1()"/>  
<input type="radio" name="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED" data-role="none" value="NO" onclick="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED1()"/>
```

How to select radio box by using radio button value.For example i want radio button to be selected for NO value.It should come like this

```
 <input type="radio" name="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED" data-role="none" value="NO" onclick="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED1()" cheked="checked"/>
```

Comment: Not getting "it should come like this"

Comment: I would suggest giving your inputs id values, eg. `id='radioButtonNo'` and `id='radioButtonYes'` for cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED'][value='NO']").attr('checked', true);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qKEgL/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name='IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED']").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'NO') {
         $(this).attr('checked','checked');   
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/74VQ3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
$("[name=IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED][value=NO]").attr("checked", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4286/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED'][value='NO']").attr('checked','checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

why do not you just give it id and select it

```
<input id"rdNo" type="radio" name="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED" data-role="none" value="NO" onclick="IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED1()"/>

$("#rdNo")...;
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector to select the radio button with a value of `NO` (assuming the name is needed) would be:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED'][value='NO']")
```

To make it checked (using jQuery 1.6+) you would use:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED'][value='NO']").prop("checked", true);
```

To make it checked (using < jQuery 1.6) you would use:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='IS_INCOMEPROOF_VERFIED'][value='NO']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sNSTd/) is a working jsFiddle example.

To make your code cleaner and allow for easier selection it would be advisable to give all of your `input` elements unique IDs.